# Complex solutions for $\Gamma(x)=-x$

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, special-functions, gamma-function

How to find complex solutions for the following equation:

> $\Gamma(x)=-x$

We can find the real solutions to be only negative by plotting both on 2D plane.

> But how to find complex solution? If possible can we get an upper bound on real part of complex solution?

Comment: It is possible to visualize the roots on a $2D$ plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this is a purely numerical work. Grphing shows where are, more or less the solutions and Newton method converges like a charm. For example, some iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.100000\pm1.000000\,i \\
 1 & 0.090610\pm0.765230 \, i \\
 2 & 0.088850\pm0.794651 \,i \\
 3 & 0.088566\pm0.795376 \,i \\
 4 & 0.088566\pm0.795377 \,i
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -1.50000\pm0.50000 \,i \\
 1 & -1.73488\pm0.22858 \,i \\
 2 & -1.66916\pm0.25561 \,i \\
 3 & -1.66190\pm0.26103 \,i \\
 4 & -1.66187\pm0.26111 \,i
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Beside numerical methods, for the real roots, you can have quite good approximations using series expansion. For example, around $x=-3^-$

$$\Gamma(x)+x=-\frac{1}{6 (x+3)}+\left(\frac{\gamma
   }{6}-\frac{119}{36}\right)+O\left((x+3)\right)$$ gives
$$x \sim -3+\frac{6}{6 \gamma -119}=-3.05193$$ while the "exact" solution is $-3.05141$.

Similarly, around $x=-4^+$

$$\Gamma(x)+x=\frac{1}{24 (x+4)}+\left(-\frac{1127}{288}-\frac{\gamma
   }{24}\right)+O\left((x+4)\right)$$
gives
$$x \sim -4+\frac{12}{1127+12 \gamma }=-3.98942$$ while the "exact" solution is $-3.98939$.